# How to print a Stack data structure in OCaml

Tags: data-structures, printing, stack, ocaml

Anyone can tell how to print a Stack data structure in OCaml?
The build-in Stack type definition is like :

```
type 'a t = { mutable c : 'a list }
exception Empty
let create () = { c = [] }
let clear s = s.c <- []
let push x s = s.c <- x :: s.c
let pop s = match s.c with hd::tl -> s.c <- tl; hd | [] -> raise Empty
let length s = List.length s.c
let iter f s = List.iter f s.c
```

Want to print and keep its elements in place, which means do not use `pop` and `push`.

**Better to use the pattern matching to complete the problem.**

Code should be like:

```
let print_stack stack =???
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally get the answer:**

```
let rec print_s {c=l}=
    match l with
    | [] -> raise Empty
    | [x] -> print_int x; print_string " "
    | h :: ts -> print_int h; print_string " "; print_s {c=ts}
;;
```

**Improved version:**

```
let print_s2 {c=l}=
    let rec print_l list =
        match list with
        | [] -> raise Empty
        | [x] -> print_int x; print_string " "
        | h :: ts -> print_int h; print_string " "; print_l ts
    in
        print_l l
;;
```

Comment: This looks good, it has the right shape. It would be slightly more efficient to traverse the list inside the stack rather than making new stacks as you progress down the list. I also don't see any reason to raise an exception forr an empty stack, but maybe this is appropriate for your intended use. Maybe you could just print `"Empty"`.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like it could be homework. You should show something you've tried that didn't work, and explain why you think it didn't work. This is a lot more valuable that just having somebody give you the answer.

If it's not homework: if you think about it, you can find a good implementation at another place in the standard library. The implementation of `Stack.iter` tells you where to look.

Comment: It's not homework. But on the way of learning by myself. 
Thanks for your previous answer to my pattern matching question about OCaml, that gives me the hint of solving this problem.

Comment: I'm happy to write the code for you; it's pretty trivial. But you could just look at `List.iter`. It shows the basic pattern, and might be more enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the function `Stack.iter` does exactly what you want:

```
let print_stack print_elem stack = Stack.iter print_elem
```

Where. `print_elem` prints one element of the stack.

e.g. `let print_elem_int n = (print_int n; print_newline ())`

Comment: Yes, it can solve the problem. But actually I want to use the pattern matching to traverses the Stack structure. Any idea about that?

Comment: You can't use pattern matching with the standard library's module since the type `Stack.t` is abstract.